# Telegram Client (not Bot) - Get photo URL

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, telegram

I'm currently using the Telegram Client API (not Bot) and I'm looking to get the URL of a photo when shared in a chat.

Many of the Telegram Bot answers on how to get the Photo URL invole getting the file/photo ID and requesting it using:

> https://api.telegram.org/bot<token_of_your_bot>/getFile?file_id=<file_id
> of the picture>

But as a Telegram Client I dont have a bot token, I have instead an Api ID and Hash.

How can I find the URL of the image in Javascript / TS.

Currently using this JS package.

> import { TelegramClient } from 'telegram'